# Кто нибудь может накидать вариантов почему такие разрывы в коде?

Tags: php, битрикс

view-source:sblregion.ru

Немного поясню.
Сайт работает на битриксе, разрывы появляются только после выполнения инклюда меню, убрать меню и всё норм. 
Но в коде самого меню и обтекающих элементов никаких проблем не найдено, что же тогда может создавать такие разрывы?
Есть варианты у кого нибудь?

Вот инклюд

```
<div class="adaptiv">
  <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "main_responsive", Array(
                "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",  // Тип меню для первого уровня
                "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",   // Тип кеширования
                "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",    // Время кеширования (сек.)
                "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
                "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "",    // Значимые переменные запроса
                "MAX_LEVEL" => "1", // Уровень вложенности меню
                "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",    // Тип меню для остальных уровней
                "USE_EXT" => "N",   // Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php
                "DELAY" => "N", // Откладывать выполнение шаблона меню
                "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",    // Разрешить несколько активных пунктов одновременно
                ),
                false
            );?>
        </div>
```

Содержание инклюда

```
<?if (!empty($arResult)):?>
<ul id="menu__adaptiv">
<?
$previousLevel = 0;
foreach($arResult as $arItem):?>
  <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
    <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>
  <?endif?>
  <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]):?>
    <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
      <li class="menu__adaptiv_item <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>">
                <a class="menu__adaptiv_link" href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>">
                        <span class="adap_plus"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>
                </a>
        <ul class="adaptiv_menu">
    <?else:?>
      <li class="adaptiv_menu_item <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="adaptiv_menu_link parent"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
        <ul>
    <?endif?>
  <?else:?>
    <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"):?>
      <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
        <li class="menu__adaptiv_item <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="menu__adaptiv_link"><span><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span></a></li>
      <?else:?>
        <li class="adaptiv_menu_item <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="adaptiv_menu_link"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
      <?endif?>
    <?else:?>
      <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
        <li class="menu__adaptiv_item"><a href="" class="menu__adaptiv_link denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
      <?else:?>
        <li class="adaptiv_menu_item"><a href="" class="adaptiv_menu_link denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
      <?endif?>
    <?endif?>
  <?endif?>
  <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"];?>
<?endforeach?>
<?if ($previousLevel > 1)://close last item tags?>
  <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel-1) );?>
<?endif?>
</ul>
<?endif?>
<a class="menu__adaptiv_close"><img src="/i/close.png" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: что Вы называете разрывом? если это "разрывы" между элементами при выводе - можете показать оба варианта: как было нормально и как испортилось?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Автор, судя по всему, под разрывом понимает где-то 700 пустых строк между строчками `<div class="adaptiv">` и `<ul id="menu__adaptiv">` в исходном коде страницы, отданном браузеру. Выглядит это действительно оригинально.

Comment: @Yaant Там дальше еще два таких же тоже примерно по 700 строк

Comment: Вы правите файлики через админку, либо же через SFTP?

Comment: @Oleksandr filezilla

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте решить проблему вот так:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "main_responsive", Array(
                "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",  // Тип меню для первого уровня
                "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",   // Тип кеширования
                "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",    // Время кеширования (сек.)
                "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
                "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => "",    // Значимые переменные запроса
                "MAX_LEVEL" => "1", // Уровень вложенности меню
                "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",    // Тип меню для остальных уровней
                "USE_EXT" => "N",   // Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php
                "DELAY" => "N", // Откладывать выполнение шаблона меню
                "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",    // Разрешить несколько активных пунктов одновременно
                ),
                false
            );
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
<?=trim($out);?>
```

Comment: увы но не подходит

Answer (score -1):

**РЕШЕНО:**
Перешел в редактирование пунктов меню "как файл" и обнаружил там около 700 строк пробелов! 4 дня искал проблему.